# Как поменять значение строки char* array = "abc" через функцию?

Tags: c++, указатели

У меня такой код. 
Есть функция

```
void chchar(char* ch){
  ch = "asfafgag";
}
```

Почему после выполнения такого кода, array не равен "asfafgag"?

```
char* array = "abc";
chchar(array);
cout << array;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Ваша переменная `array` имеет тип `const char*`, не `char*`.
2. Потому что происходит неявное копирование переданных данных.

Для того что бы в `C++` записать в переданный указатель на строку, вам необходимо:

1. Выделить память из кучи.
2. Передать указатель по ссылке, или же передать указатель на указатель, "разыменовать" указатель, и записать в него данные.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void chchar(char** str)
{
    strcpy(*str, "String data from `chchar`");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* data = static_cast<char*>(malloc(sizeof(100)));
    strcpy(data, "Blablbla");
    printf("Data before call `chchar`: %s\n", data);
    chchar(&data);
    printf("Data after call `chchar`: %s\n", data);
    free(data);
    system("pause");
}
```

Так же можно указатель на строку передать по ссылке:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void chchar(char*& str)
{
    strcpy(str, "String data from `chchar`");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* data = static_cast<char*>(malloc(sizeof(100)));
    strcpy(data, "Blablbla");
    printf("Data before call `chchar`: %s\n", data);
    chchar(data);
    printf("Data after call `chchar`: %s\n", data);
    free(data);
    system("pause");
}
```

Результат обоих случаев:

```
Data before call `chchar`: Blablbla
Data before call `chchar`: String data from `chchar`
```

Пример: https://ideone.com/1W85dS

Answer (score 1):

В функции вы меняете значение указателя на строку, тем самым вы не меняете внешнюю переменную указателя, а меняете адрес указателя, в итоге получается, что вы просто поменяли адрес локальной переменной.

Для выноса изменения наружу нужен указатель на указатель, и изменять его.

```
void chchar(char** a);

int main()
{
  char* array [] = {"sdf"};
  chchar(array );
  std::cout << "Hello, " << *array << "!\n";
}

void chchar(char** a){
    *a = {"asfafgag"};
}
```

Comment: Ваш `array` является константной строкой.

Comment: Не, этот array является указателем на указатель строки, а в функции мы меняем адрес указателя.

Comment: `warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]`

Comment: И? ну так да `warning` дело говорит, действительно не стоит в плюсах использовать указатели на строки и там ещё куча замечаний можно привести, но это компилится и работает.

Comment: А я могу конкретно такой вариант написания char* array = "abc"; поменять через функцию ?

Comment: @breeze: Вы измените не строку! Вы измените адрес указателя на строку.

Comment: @breeze Если вам нужно сохранить адрес первого элемента, то тогда вам нужно изучить ответ Yami